# Issue with playing some .mp4 on Google Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have downloaded some .mp4 files from shutterstock to use them in my website project.

Everything works perfect on localhost, i can play the movies like localhost/example.mp4 on every browser. I uploaded the files on my server, but now, it won`t play with Google Chrome (myserver.com/example.mp4), but will play with other browsers. This is very strange.

Anyone have any explanation ?

I checked the mime types in my cPanel account and all are ok, also i added the next code into htaccess but still doesn`t work.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
AddType video/webm .webm
```

and

```
<FilesMatch mp4>
Satisfy any
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What should be the issue? Is a file issue or an issue from the server? Cues from localhost it will open in Google Chrome.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am struggling with getting .mp4 to have the 'Cast' option in Chrome on Android, but only when there is a .htaccess file. I assume it has to do with the Basic Auth I am using to protect the folder containing the files.

Comment: @JustinT. It's been 3 years from this post, It was a small task and I don't remember what happened exactly. Sorry :(

Comment: Thanks for the response, I actually found out what was causing the issue and I have it working now. Thanks again!